# ASP.NET file transfer from local machine to another machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, localhost, transfer

I basically want to transfer a file from the client to the file storage server without actual login to the server so that the client cannot access the storage location on the server directly. I can do this only if i manually login to the storage server through windows login. I dont want to do that. This is a Web-Based Application.

Using the link below, I wrote a code for my application. I am not able to get it right though, Please refer the link and help me ot with it...

[Uploading files to file server using webclient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263518/c-uploading-files-to-file-server)

---

The following is my code:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    filePath = FileUpload1.FileName;     
    try 
    { 
        WebClient client = new WebClient(); 

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(uName, password); 

        Uri addy = new Uri("\\\\192.168.1.3\\upload\\"); 
        client.Credentials = nc; 
        byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, filePath); 

        Console.WriteLine(arrReturn.ToString()); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    } 

}
```

The following line doesn't execute...

```
byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, filePath);
```

This is the error I get:

> An exception occurred during a
>   WebClient request

Comment: Hi,

is it possible that there is an inner exception? Is mapping the share locally as a drive an option?

-sa

Comment: Display ex.ToString() instead of ex.Message, and you'll get the full exception. Edit your question to include the full exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it seems (and with good reason), the `FileUpload` can only save files to the web server and its drives. So my first thought won't work.

But: if you have the necessary permissions, couldn't you just save the file that you get in the FileUpload to that UNC path using standard System.IO calls?? Something like :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        string completeFileName = 
           Path.Combine(@"\\192.168.1.3\upload", FileUpload1.FileName); 

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

        FileStream fstm = new FileStream(completeFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fstm);

        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
        br.Close();

        bw.Write(buffer);
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    } 
}
```

If you expect very large files to be uploaded, you might want to transfer the data from the `BinaryReader` to the `BinaryWriter` in chunks - instead of allocating just a single buffer - but that's just an implementation detail, really.

Comment: It gives me this error:-

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: @Imcl: yes, seems the FileUpload control can't write to a remote location - updated my answer

Comment: this line isnt executed and it enters the catch block showing the same error as above:-

FileStream fstm = new FileStream(completeFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

Comment: I even added these lines in the try block:-

WebClient client = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(uName, password);
client.Credentials = nc;

uName and pasword are strings containing the username and password of the remote/server machine

Comment: @Imcl: well, then you obviously do not have permissions to access that path and create a file there, I would think! Can you give us the full exception (ex.ToString()) ?? Update your original post with it, please - do **not** post it here in the comments - too hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a few days ago, I solved it by creating a user on the Web server and on the storage server with the same user name and password, I then impersonated  the user in the web.config file.

NB: The user should have RW permissions in the directory where you want to store the files.